# Enable Inkscape checkerboard background by default

Tags: inkscape

Since Inkscape 0.92 it's possible to have a checkerboard background in the document settings.

I noticed that Inkscape SVGs that have the checkerboard enabled have the `inkscape:pagecheckerboard="true"` attribute. I tried adding that to the `<group id="template">` in `~/.config/inkscape/preferences.xml`, but that doesn't work, and the file is overwritten when I open Inkscape.

How can I enable the checkerboard background as default for new documents?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out: You just save an svg file with the checkerboard enabled and copy it to `~/.config/inkscape/default.svg`.

Comment: For Windows users, the `default.svg` file is in the Inkscape install directory: `C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\templates\default.svg`

Comment: Hmmm, almost worked for me. Had to place the `default.svg` into `.config/inkscape/templates/` instead

Comment: Is it possible to set the checkerboard background as replacement to transparent background?

Comment: This doesn't work for files that are saved and re-opened as e.g. Optimized SVG. i.e. this preference doesn't affect the default for SVG files opened from external sources, which will always have a white background, even if they solely consist of white shapes :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in UI

1. Set up any changes to the default empty document.
2. in this case go to **File** > **Document Properties** and set checkboard
3. **File** > **Save Template**
4. and in pop up check the option: "**set as a default template**"

Answer (score 1):

In file:

```
%APPDATA%\inkscape\preferences.xml
```

Change:

```
pagecheckerboard="0"
```

to:

```
pagecheckerboard="1"
```